# How to create a vertical line on a certain date at x axis in Spotfire

Tags: dashboard, spotfire

[image]

Hi guys,

How to create a vertical line to a certain date on X axis? I found out that we will need to set x axis as
continuous scale to enable vertical line option...But this is not what I want. For example, I have attached a screenshot. I manually set the vertical line in August 2013...of course, this is not what i want to do (I can't manually input a date as i want the chart to analyze it), but that is the final look i want. I want the chart to read the date when it has the first water injection from well list i imported and then draw a vertical line on that date...From this date to future, it will be the waterflood period (it will be nice to somehow highlight this area in the chart with a light color but i dont know how to do it). Can somebody tell me what I need to do to achieve this and I do want x axis to be categorical scale as i want to show all dates.... Is there a custom curve script I can write? I assume i would need to write something like read the earliest date of the water injection and then draw a vertical line on this date...

Please help! Thanks!